# How to train multi item timeseries forecasting in Sagemaker?

Tags: time-series, amazon-sagemaker, forecast, aiml, sku

I have data like below.

```
   date      sku   unitprice    trand_item    target
2018-01-01    A      10            Black        3
2018-01-02    A      10            Black        7
2018-01-03    A      10            Black        0
2018-01-04    A      10            Black        13
.
.
.
2017-08-01    B      20            White        4
2017-08-02    B      20            White        0
2017-08-03    B      20            White        17
2017-08-04    B      20            White        9
.
.
.
```

Every timestamp is filled in 'D' without blank and 'sku' is item number.
I have 25 items and i want to forecast 'target'.
Also want to use 'unit price', 'trand_item' for meta data.

How can i train timeseries forecasting model in sagemaker?
1 model for 25 items. (For example, i want to forecast 30days for each item's 'target'.)

Please help me...

Answer (score 0):

If you have at least 300 rows you can use [DeepAR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/deepar.html). It supports grouping, such as by SKU

Otherwise, you'd want to [bring your own algorithm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers-notebooks.html), such as [sktime](https://www.sktime.org/en/stable/)